# How to save pictures from Firefox without re-downloading

Tags: firefox, download

A big jpeg picture file is opened in Firefox. If I do "Save As" for it it downloads the picture again to save it.

How can I save the currently opened picture without re-downloading it in Firefox?

Comment: It looks like this is [bug #288462](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=288462) (since [bug #120809](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=120809) is supposed to be fixed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the picture from firefox's cache, use this [cache viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mozilla_cache_viewer.html) to get the picture.